# Perspective Transformation for bird's eye view opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, perspective

I am interested in perspective transformation to bird's eye view. So far I have tried getPerspectiveTransform and findHomography and then passing it onto warpPerspective. The results are quite close but a skew in TL and BR is present. Also the contourArea are not translated equally post transformation.

The contour is a square with multiple shapes inside.

Any suggestion on how to go ahead.

Code block of what I have done so far.

```
    std::vector<Point2f> quad_pts;
    std::vector<Point2f> squre_pts;    

    cv::approxPolyDP( Mat(validContours[largest_contour_index]), contours_poly[0], epsilon, true );

    if (approx_poly.size() > 4) return false;

    for (int i=0; i< 4; i++)
            quad_pts.push_back(contours_poly[0][i]);

    if (! orderRectPoints(quad_pts))
            return false;

    float widthTop = (float)distanceBetweenPoints(quad_pts[1], quad_pts[0]); // sqrt( pow(quad_pts[1].x - quad_pts[0].x, 2) + pow(quad_pts[1].y - quad_pts[0].y, 2));
    float widthBottom = (float)distanceBetweenPoints(quad_pts[2], quad_pts[3]); // sqrt( pow(quad_pts[2].x - quad_pts[3].x, 2) + pow(quad_pts[2].y - quad_pts[3].y, 2));

    float maxWidth = max(widthTop, widthBottom);

    float heightLeft = (float)distanceBetweenPoints(quad_pts[1], quad_pts[2]); // sqrt( pow(quad_pts[1].x - quad_pts[2].x, 2) + pow(quad_pts[1].y - quad_pts[2].y, 2));
    float heightRight = (float)distanceBetweenPoints(quad_pts[0], quad_pts[3]); // sqrt( pow(quad_pts[0].x - quad_pts[3].x, 2) + pow(quad_pts[0].y - quad_pts[3].y, 2));

    float maxHeight = max(heightLeft, heightRight);
    int mDist = (int)max(maxWidth, maxHeight);

    // transform TO points
    const int offset = 50;
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(offset, offset));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(mDist-1, offset));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(mDist-1, mDist-1));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(offset, mDist-1));

    maxWidth += offset; maxHeight += offset;
    Size matSize ((int)maxWidth, (int)maxHeight);

    Mat transmtx = getPerspectiveTransform(quad_pts, squre_pts);
   //  Mat homo = findHomography(quad_pts, squre_pts);
    warpPerspective(mRgba, mRgba, transmtx, matSize);
    return true;
```

[Link to transformed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1JJn.png)

[Image pre-transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqCg6.png)

[corner on pre-transformed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ZzI.png)

[Corners from CornerSubPix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9T6k.png)

Comment: As can be seen in the image, the straight red line does not pass through the middle of extreme contours. Also my contour areas are not even/uniform for the ones I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original pre-transformation image is not so good, the squares have different sizes there and it looks wavy. The results you get are quite good given the quality of your input.

You could try to calibrate your camera (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) to compensate lens distortion, and your results may improve.

EDIT: Just to summarize the comments below, approxPolyDp may not locate the corners properly if the square has rounded corners or it is blurred. You may need to improve the corner location by other means such as a sharper original image, different preprocessing (median filter or threshold, as you suggest in the comments), or other algorithms for finer corner location (such as using the cornersubpix function or detecting the sides with Hough Transform and then calculating the intersections of them)

Comment: I would like to avoid using camera calibration or the intrinsic parameters.

Like i mentioned before, the TL and BR are not straight. Is it possible to straighten them based on some parameters?

Comment: I would draw quad_pts on your original pre-transformed image and see what contour has found. As the edges of the rectangle in the image are not straight (they are kind of round or wavy), the quad that it finds may have a small error of 1 or 2 pixels, which is enough  for causing the error that you notice in the output,

Comment: Added corner_0.png to the original post. You are right that the lines are wavy, could MatSize play a role in final transformation (basically pixel ratio)?

Comment: ApproxPolyDP is not locating the corners accurately because they look rounded in your image, maybe they are just blurred. If a corner is round, the function picks one of those pixels, and it is not picking the central one. You should print a square with sharper corners (not rounded). Another option is locating the corners with a more complex algorithm, for example finding the sides with the Hough Transform and then calculating the intersection of the lines (this would be more precise as the corners would have decimal precision)

Comment: Thanks @user2518618, this could be the reason. Will try your suggestion.

Was trying something more complex like calculate median center (TL-BR and TR-BL), and then computing the transformation points off that, but still notice a skew.

Comment: Changed the inner contour to square, quite visible that the edges are not being detected correctly (new square corner link in original post). Any suggestion to improve on approxPolyDP?

Comment: One issue that I notice is that I am using Point for edge detection from approxPolyDP, while I use float in the rest of the places. The edge seems to have improved after using vector<Point2f> contours_poly(1).
The blurriness of edges is having an impact, not sure if switching to threshold/canny image will help.

Comment: After you have roughly located the corners, maybe you can use cornersubpix https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/corner_subpixeles/corner_subpixeles.html to improve the location

Comment: Thanks @user2518618,  Currently improved the edge detection by adjusting threshold parameters. Also switched from medianBlur to GaussianBlur.
Will try out your suggestion as well, but figured the amount of points in Contours stored will be key to finer detection. Currently 480x640 pixels to avoid hitting processing performance.

Comment: I was able to use your suggestion on cornerSubPix (ref: [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9T6k.png) here to arrive very close. The final transformation is not shaping up perfectly, but that is probably the maths that need to be tweaked.
I had to use a mask to avoid detection corners anywhere in the image, which included masking the contour outside(with threshold) as well as inside. Really appreciate your help.
Final transformation still has a skew of around 0.5 degree across.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429502/opencv-optimized-shared-library-for-android